# Scala 3 Using - problems when reading from file

Tags: scala

In a Scala 3 project, I have a method which returns a Try from a given String

```
def translate(text: String) : Try[Thing] = ...
```

and a method which is supposed to read the contents of a file and pass it on to the first method. Here, I want to use `Using` because as far as I understand, this is the functional way to handle file I/O, and it returns a `Try` which I need anyway, and it makes sure the used resource is closed:

```
  def translateFromFile(filepath: String) : Try[Thing] =
    Using(Source.fromFile(filepath).getLines.mkString) match
      case Success(s) => translate(s)
      case Failure(e) => Failure(e)
```

However, the compiler says

`given instance of type scala.util.Using.Releasable[String] was found for parameter evidence$1 of method apply in object Using`

Honestly, I don't understand this error message, and I couldn't find any help online. Can someone help? What's the correct way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error means that you're trying to substitute into `Using(...)` not something that can be closed but a `String`.

It should be

```scala
def translateFromFile(filepath: String) : Try[Thing] =
  Using(Source.fromFile(filepath)) { s =>
    translate(s.getLines.mkString) match {
      case Success(s) => ???
      case Failure(e) => ???
    }
  }
```

or just

```scala
def translateFromFile(filepath: String) : Try[Thing] =
  Using(Source.fromFile(filepath)) { s =>
    translate(s.getLines.mkString)
  }.flatten
```

`Using(...){s => ...}` returns `Try` and your `translate` returns `Try`, so it's `Try[Try[...]]`, that's why `.flatten`.

There is nothing specific to Scala 3.

Comment: Instead of `flatten` you could also try `Using(Source.fromFile(filepath)) { s => s.getLines.mkString }.flatMap(translate)`.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok yeah, thanks `Using(Source.fromFile(filepath))(_.getLines.mkString).flatMap(translate)`